# Probability of hardware related disk or memory corruption?

Tags: sqlite, hardware, corruption

I've got a few hundred computers running an app.  On one computer, I've seen two instances of a single bit being incorrectly set on some strings that I pull out of SQLite.  If this was my dev computer I would assume I have a bug somewhere, but there is certainly some number of installations at which point I'll start seeing rare hardware based errors.

This is certainly dependent on how much IO I do, but are there any rules of thumbs for when there is a decent chance of seeing this kind of thing?  For example, for TCP packets, [this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=347059.347561) determined that silent, undetected corruption will occur in "roughly 1 in 16 million to 10 billion packets".

Unfortunately, running a mem/disk checker on the machine in question is not likely to happen.

Answer (score 4):

When I notice strange things happening, my strategy is:

1. check if there is a bug **in the code**
2. check if there is a bug in the used library/tool (SQLite, here)
3. check if there is a bug **in the compiler**
4. then, and only then, check for hardware faults

In my 10 years-long career, 99,99% of bugs were software related.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should also add checking the driver or IO controller if working on a customised OS.

Comment: Good advice! fortunately hardware faults are alot easier to rule out quickly by simply switching the test hardware and seeing if the fault moves. If the hardware is different enough and you are still failing, good chance its not hardware.

Comment: In -my- experience hardware, disks and RAM are so faulty. Its not 99.99%.

Answer (score 2):

Bit errors will happen.  Consider protecting your data with CRC's or some other kind of error detection/correction mechanism.  The odds of it happening are dependant on what kind of hardware you have.  If you have memory with ECC, then it's going to be less likely than if you don't for instance, but even ECC memory goes bad and may fail to correct errors.  With several hundred computers I would say the odd hardware error is going to be very likely, probably certain, to happen daily.

Answer (score 1):

["Wikipedia: ECC memory"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory)
says
"Recent DRAM tests give widely varying error rates with over 7 orders of magnitude difference, ranging from 10^−10 to 10^−17 error/bit·h, roughly one bit error, per hour, per gigabyte of memory to one bit error, per century, per gigabyte of memory.[7][11][12]"

Even if we use the most optimistic estimate of one bit error per century per gigabyte, if you have a cluster of 100 computers with 2 GB of RAM each, that implies that you'll see a bit error twice a year.
(This only includes RAM bit error. You mentioned TCP packet undetected corruption, and you might also consider disk drive failures, accidental power cord unplugging, cooling fan failures, etc).
The more pessimistic estimates imply you'll see bit errors far more often -- as Steve Baker said, bit errors are inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

with subtle errors, it can happen anytime, and from several source, even the [most unlikely](http://www.newscientist.com/blog/technology/2008/03/do-we-need-cosmic-ray-alerts-for.html).

As you can see errors occurring on a single machine, your best option is to handle the damage instead of relying on statistics to tell you when something might go wrong. Whilst the errors might be due to external factors, if you've seen more than one it would be prudent to get that memchecker running on the machine to check that its not faulty hardware. The alternative is trusting to luck that you won't see a total failure.

Answer (score 0):

Switch that machine out. In my current position (~7 years) I've seen a bluescreen caused by a hardware memory error once.  If you are seeing bit error failures on the same machine twice, good chance you've found the culprit.  In the same period of time I've seen dozens of disk controller failure/disk failure/registry corruption bluescreens. So they are rare, but they do happen.

On the network side, we had one case where a 3d party vendor's WAN compression device was compressing our apps TCP packets together, incorrectly, and then putting a good CRC on it. That wreaked havoc to say the least.

Comment: If you are seeing what you think are bit errors on more than one machine, don't bother switching the machine ;)